# AttributeError: __enter__ with Appjar subWindow GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I have written some GUI with python using [appJar](http://appjar.info/). I am trying to start the application with the login Subwindow. However when I run the code I get the error "AttributeError: **enter**" Hopefully someone can let me know what I am doing wrong. This is my first time using GUI.

**Full Error Message:**
2018-05-01 15:24:38,521 appJar:ERROR [Line 40->1630/**exit**]: ContextManager failed: **enter**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jason Smit/PycharmProjects/Project-X/main.py", line 17, in 
    with app.startSubWindow("Sub1", "LogWin",):
AttributeError: **enter**

```
    def login(btn):
    if btn == "Unlock":
        app.infoBox("Success", "Access granted\n Welcome User")
        app.hideSubWindow("Sub1")
    return

###################
# GUI starts here # 
###################

with gui("Project-X") as app:
    app.setBg("white")
    app.setIcon("app_icon.ico")  # App icon
    with app.startSubWindow("Sub1", "LogWin",):
        # Empty left container (To help get login in center.)
        with app.frame("LEFT", row=0, column=0, sticky='NEW', stretch='COLUMN'):
            """"""
        # Login container/gui

        with app.frame("CenterTop", row=0, column=1, sticky='NEW', stretch='column'):
            app.setBg("white")
            with app.labelFrame("Login"):
                app.setBg("white")
                app.setSticky("ew")
                # Login widget setup
                app.addLabel("l1", "Name", 0, 0)
                app.addEntry("Name", 0, 1)
                app.addLabel("l2", "Password", 1, 0)
                app.addSecretEntry("Password", 1, 1)
                app.addNamedButton("Submit", "Unlock", login, 2, 0, 2)

        # Empty right container (To help get login in center.)

        with app.frame("RIGHT", row=0, column=2,  sticky='NEW', stretch='COLUMN'):
            """"""
        app.stopSubWindow()
    app.go(startWindow="Sub1")
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, including stack trace.

Comment: @user2357112 I have updated the post, hopefully that is what you were asking for. It is the full error that appears when I try run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The context manager is `subWindow`, not `startSubWindow`](http://appjar.info/pythonContextManager/):

```
with app.subWindow("Sub1", "LogWin"):
```